# drupal:object not found error on every link other than home page

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-8

After installing and configuring drupal 8 site,home page in displayed perfectly,but when i navigate to any link Object not found error is thrown.I am using xampp.Writing RewriteBase /drupal in /sites/default/files/.htaccess file  didnt fix the error.AllowOverride is all in directory lampp/htdocs/.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think, drupal missed to place its default htaccess file in the drupal root folder. I fixed the same by copying the htaccess from the drupal zip file and placed it in the root folder. Also make sure mod_rewrite is also enabled in Apache Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux for server then execute below command.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod env
sudo a2enmod dir
sudo a2enmod mime
```

It works in my case.